# When does Facebook Page Conversation webhook is triggered?

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know when Facebook triggers this webhook?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/#conversations

I suppose to get thread id from this webhook, but seem that it never triggered no matter how I change the conversation (e.g make new conversation, change flags,...)

Comment: Are you sure you subscribed correctly?

Comment: I got the callback from FB when using Test button, so the subscription must be ok.

Comment: What does that button test _exactly_ - just whether your callback URL is set up correctly? That does not mean that you have subscribed for updates for a specific page yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that it takes quite long time before it starting to send conversation callback. It works OK now.

Comment: May I know how long does it take to send the first callback? I'm having the same issue as your question.

Comment: Same thing here